# How to quickly tell if a set is linearly independent or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

Before proving if a set is a basis for $R^n$, I have to determine if the set is linearly independent or not. 
We aren't allowed to use matrices, and I want to save time during a quiz.

What are some things I should watch out for?

Comment: I had a typo in my previous comment (and it's been more than 5 minutes so I'm fixing it here): If you have $n+1$ (or more) vectors, they must be linearly dependent. If you can see that one is a multiple of another vector (or a sum of two or more vectors), then the set is linearly dependent. This is not always easy to see, however.

Comment: If the set contains the zero vector its dependent

Comment: If there are $n$ vectors but the $i$th coordinate is always zero then its dependent (more generally: if there are $n-k$ vectors and $k+1$ many coordinates which are always 0)

Comment: Note that *the* quick way to check this is to set up the linear independence equation in matrix form, then ask a computer to compute the coefficient matrix's determinant. (It's good to remember that problems often have better solutions than what a class forces you to use.)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

- The set contains the zero vector
- You can write an element as a linear combination of the others
- If the dimension of your vector space is $n$, then any set that contains more $n$ will be linearly dependent.

The first and third points are easy to check, while the second will just require some quick arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The two basic observations, as others have pointed out, are that if there are more vectors than the dimension of the vector space, or if the zero vector is in the set, you surely have a dependent set. Additionally if there are identical vectors in the set, the set is dependent too (obviously). Other than this, there is no easy and quick way to check whether a set of vectors is dependant without using matrices (if you are allowed, just use row reduction to find the rank of the matrix whose column vectors are in the set, which conveniently tells you the number of independent vectors as well).